# Insert into SQL Server has failed due to invalid data length error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Column of type `nvarchar(max)` in a SQL Server table throws an error when we try to insert a value that is greater than 5000 characters through Informatica.

The error is:

> Invalid data length or metadata length

Data load succeeds when we insert value that has lesser than 5000 characters.

What could be the reason for this failure?

Comment: What are you using to insert? Check this: https://kb.informatica.com/solution/23/Pages/55/379764.aspx

Comment: Informatica Powercenter 10.2.0. Source is Oracle and Target is SQL Server.

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Thanks @JacobH

Comment: No problem! Google fu has taken me far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to below given article.

https://kb.informatica.com/solution/23/Pages/55/379764.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, changing the type from **nvarchar(max)** to **ntext** solved the issue.